# Online registration error

Tags: civievent, error, online-registration, drupal-7

Trying to set up online registration. All events get the following error message: "Error Online registration is not currently available for this event (contact the site administrator for assistance)."

CiviCRM 5.33.2 on Drupal 7

Comment: Maybe a silly question but do you have Allow Online Registration checked on the Online Registration tab under the event config?

Comment: Not a silly question, just too obvious I suppose. Thanks @Demerit for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @demerit you will need to enable online registration for the event. You see the option for turning on online registration under 'Online registration' tab of event.

[image]